# How to create a MPRIS2 server

Tags: linux, dbus

I am trying to connect a media player to MPRIS via an intermediary program. This app (musicbee) allows me to make plugins exposing all functionality that MPRIS needs. I am then trying to write a middleman program that will be able to take media information, push that to the bus, and listen for media commands like pause/play, etc.

Note that the hard part (for me) is connecting the middleman to mpris.

I already tried [mpris-server](https://pypi.org/project/mpris-server/) which was challenging. I decided to use the [recommended project](https://github.com/alexdelorenzo/cast_control) as inspiration. It was fishy since it calls for an mpris_server version >= 0.7.0, but I made the necessary changes and renames and got quite far.

Then i got this on mpris.loop()

```
venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:123: Warning: g_variant_builder_end: assertion 'GVSB(builder)->offset >= GVSB(builder)->min_items' failed
  return builder.end()
ERROR:pydbus.registration:Exception while handling org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydbus/registration.py", line 81, in call_method
    result = method(*parameters, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydbus/registration.py", line 110, in GetAll
    ret[local] = GLib.Variant(type, getattr(self.object, local))
  File "venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 190, in __new__
    v.format_string = format_string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format_string'
```

I looked into this, and found

```
if not GLib.VariantType.string_is_valid(format_string):
    raise TypeError("Invalid GVariant format string '%s'", format_string)
creator = _VariantCreator()
v = creator._create(format_string, value)
v.format_string = format_string
```

which makes `v` = `None` when `ret[local] = GLib.Variant(type, getattr(self.object, local))` local = 'ActivePlaylist'

This is set automatically in the mpris construction, and my demo project did nothing special.

I feel like this is a dead end.